# Difference between token transactions number and same token smart contract transactions number

Tags: solidity, transactions, blockchain, tokens, etherscan

On Etherscan the token analytics of the contract (https://etherscan.io/token/0x799a4202c12ca952cb311598a024c80ed371a41e) shows the total 1991 transactions while the same token contract (https://etherscan.io/txs?a=0x799a4202c12ca952cb311598a024c80ed371a41e) shows the 1935 transaction even the ERC20 token transaction section contain only 2 transactions by adding this we are still not near to token transactions number even adding the internal transaction we have a higher number. How the token transactions number are larger than the contract transaction? Why do they have differences? Is there any other way to hold the token without interacting with the contract?

Answer (score 2):

I believe Etherscan shows "contract transactions" as transactions, which have that contract as their original destination. So 1991 transactions have originally targeted that contract.

A contract may perform multiple operations. It may for example call two different token contracts and do some operations there. So if you call contract A which transfers token B (so *you -> A -> B*), A gets probably one transaction more and B gets one token transaction more.

It's also very possible that a token contract has other functionality besides token transfer functionality. So a token contract may have extra functionality to set some internal fee for example. Setting that fee is a transaction, but it's not a token transfer.

This way token contract transaction count can be lower or higher than token transaction count.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have bridge smart contract that transform the assets from one chain to another or one token contract to another. So, for transferring asset the user perform the transaction with bridge contract, which make the transaction the part of token transaction list because the interaction with smart contract is internally thorough message call that why it does not part of the original token contract transaction list (contain only those transaction whose "to:0xan..." parameter contain contract address) .It makes the number of transaction less than the number of token transactions